# File Path Specification PHP/HTML file upload?

Tags: php, text

I have written a php file for uploading a .txt file. I am pretty new to this, so please bear with me here.

So I will commence with the problem, basically the output I get is: "**The System Cannot find the path specified**."

---

Facts:

I manage my wwwroot files through ftp as I am using a commercial Host for my webpage.

My code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['notes'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['notes']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['notes']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['notes']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['notes']['type'];
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['notes']['name'])));
    $extensions = array("txt");
    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a txt file.";
    }
    if($file_size > 5097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be exactly 5 MB !';
    }
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/uploads".$file_name);
        echo "Successful Upload, Thanks !!";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
```

I have first tried /wwwroot/uploads (didn't work) now I have tried just /uploads.

I hope I have given you the right amount of info.

Your time is greatly appreciated!

-M

Comment: have you created the directory `/uploads` before you attempted the script?

Comment: Yes, prior to making the script, I made the 'uploads' folder in wwwroot.

Comment: If I can recall correctly, I think so time in the past, I read that you have to enable file-upload in php.ini file (?) I have no clue where to find this config file. Can that be the issue?

Comment: yes that could be it.   you can check phpinfo() and find `file_uploads` and see if it is not set to yes.

Comment: The output is:  file_uploads | On | On

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, try changing this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/uploads".$file_name);
```

To this:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
```

Edit:

Okay since changing the above removed the file path error, there may be a problem with the file itself.

try changing

```
$file_name = $_FILES['notes']['name'];
```

to

```
$file_name = basename($_FILES['notes']['name']);
```

Edit:  if this does not work,  one other important note:

You will need to set the ownership of the directory where you wish to upload to be "apache" (assuming you are using an apache server) for it to be able to accept uploads to this folder from the web.

this would be something like this:

```
chown apache:apache uploads -R
```

Then set the permissions to be 775.

--
If you are not on a Linux system, and just working on a dev server on a Windows device, there's no need.

For more error information, please place this at the top of your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: I tried it, It did not give the error! However, it didn't upload the file to the folder either ?

Comment: Truly, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Thank you, but still no actual uploads to the folder. :(

Comment: okay, this could be a server permission thing.  See the above edits (I ran into this recently myself)

Comment: How do I chown apache:apache uploads -R ?

Comment: on a command line on the server.   However if you are on your own local dev server, that might not be it.

Comment: Wow thanks man, I am truly learning here. So I placed the error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); on the top just below <?php But it didn't output anything.

Comment: yes.  that should give you a lot more information in a LOT of situations.

Comment: I am on a commercial host server, no clue how to do the chown apache:apache uploads -R thing.

Comment: you may need to discuss this with the sysadmins at the host.  however before you do that try using `var_dump()` on each of your variables to make sure the file name is getting properly passed.  for instance, `var_dump($file_name)`

Comment: Wow It worked! All It needed was a 'very hard' refresh. I basically restarted my filezilla and it showed the txt file in the folder!  Thanks everyone for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Change the destination of the file from `/uploads` to `uploads/` if your php file is in the same folder of the *uploads* folder. If not, you must insert the path of the *uploads* folder using absolute path or use `../` to direct the file to the right path.

Comment: So you mean: ../wwwroot/uploads ?

Comment: Your php file is on wwwroot/ folder?

Comment: Yes, it's a test setup

Comment: Then you should use `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);`. Make sure you have write permissions on the folder.

Comment: I just did altered that, and I set the uploads folder to 777 permission just for a raw test.

Comment: If permissions and path are working, the problem could be the file. Try the edited answer from nomistic. You could also do a `var_dump` on the `$_FILES['notes']` and on `$file_name` just to check if the values are correct.